# Connect to redis cluster in R

Tags: r, redis

Suppose there were several hosts and ports of the redis server, like

10.0.1.1:6381

10.0.1.1:6382

10.0.1.2:6381

10.0.1.2:6382

how can I configure the `redux::hiredis()`?

I have google around but can't find a solution. And I noticed that there was a note on `db` parameter of the `redis_config` function with "Do not use in a redis clustering context.", so I was wondering that this was a way to connect to a cluster. In addition, I have also try to pass `redis://10.0.1.1:6381,10.0.1.1:6382,10.0.1.2:6381,10.0.1.2:6382` to the `url` parameter, but still failed.

Any suggestions? Or is there another package you would suggest?

Answer (score 0):

My initial solution is writing a function to point to the correct node based on the error message.

```
check_redis <- function(key = "P10000", host = "10.0.1.1", port = 6381) {
  r <- redux::hiredis(host = host, port = port)
  status <- tryCatch(
    {
      r$EXISTS(key = key)
    },
    error = function(e){
      address <- str_match(e$message, 
                           "[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+:[0-9]+")
      host <- str_split(address, ":", simplify = T)[1]
      port <- str_split(address, ":", simplify = T)[2]
      return(list(host = host, port = port))
    }
  )
  if (is.list(status)) {
    r <- redux::hiredis(host = status$host, port = status$port)
  } 
  return(r)
}
```

It can help to direct to the correct node, but this solution is neither elegant nor efficient. So please advise.